# What is the correct model binding architecture for this situation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I'm replacing some old webservice code with WebApi, and I've got a situation where the code used to do something like this:

```
If Request.QueryString("value") = 1 Then
    {do first action}
Else
    {do second action}
End If
```

Each action is totally different, and each has an independent set of *other* query string parameters.

In my new version, I'm modelling this as:

```
Public Function FirstAction(model as FirstActionModel) As HttpResponseMessage
```

and

```
Public Function SecondAction(model as SecondActionModel) As HttpResponseMessage
```

The catch is that the incoming request is going to just call `/api/actions?actiontype=1&params...` or `/api/actions?actiontype=2&params...` and the params are different.

I want to be able to route a request with `actiontype=1` to `FirstAction`, and `actiontype=2` to `SecondAction`.  But I can't use routing, because the important value is in the query string, not the path.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why cannot you add action type to url like "/api/actions/action1?params..." ? You have a requirement to have it as url parameter?

Comment: I don't control the caller, so I can't switch the parameter from the query string to the path.

Comment: What you can probably do is setup a single action that will check the `actiontype` parameter and redirect/call other actions accordingly.

Comment: I tried that, but then I lose model binding.

Comment: Maybe you can use IHttpActionSelector interface? In your custom implementation you can access HttpControllerContext object and check its Request property to access url parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i've mentioned in comments you can use  IHttpActionSelector to achieve this. But instead of implementing interface directly you can inherit from default implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class CustomHttpActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector 
    {
        public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            var urlParam = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(controllerContext.Request.RequestUri.Query);
            var actionType = urlParam["actiontype"];
            if (actionType == null)
                return base.SelectAction(controllerContext);

            MethodInfo methodInfo;
            if (actionType.ToString() == "1")
                methodInfo = controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.GetMethod("Action1");
            else
                methodInfo = controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.GetMethod("Action2");

            return new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor, methodInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

And to register it you need to add following line to your `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionSelector), new CustomHttpActionSelector());
```

In your controller you than add two methods Action1 and Action2:

```
    public string Action1(string param)
    {
        return "123";
    }

    public string Action2(string param)
    {
        return "345";
    }
```

Comment: Wow, this totally worked!  Thanks so much for the info, and the detailed code samples, which made it a lot easier.